# Unit-testing in Racket with objects

Tags: unit-testing, testing, lisp, racket

I am trying to build the classic game "Snake" with Racket and Dr. Racket.

I like using unit-tests to see if I am understanding the concepts behind my code.

I started creating structure definitions for Snake and for positions in a 2 dimensions (2D) plane:

```
(struct snake (dir segs)) 

(struct posn (x y))
```

After that, I created a snake example:

```
(define snake-example
  (snake "up" (list (posn 1 1) (posn 1 2) (posn 1 3))))
```

If I try to access the segs on my snake object, I call:

```
(snake-segs snake-example)

>> '(#<posn> #<posn> #<posn>)
```

Which is the same as calling:

```
(list (posn 1 1) (posn 1 2) (posn 1 3))

>> '(#<posn> #<posn> #<posn>)
```

However, If I try using a test and rackunit to check this, it does not work:

```
(require rackunit)

(check-equal? (snake-segs snake-example) (list (posn 1 1) (posn 1 2) (posn 1 3)))
```

I get this answer:

```
FAILURE
actual:     (#<posn> #<posn> #<posn>)
expected:   (#<posn> #<posn> #<posn>)
name:       check-equal?
location:   (#<path:/home/pedro/Desktop/realm-of-racket/cap-6.rkt> 276 0 8425 81)
expression: (check-equal? (snake-segs snake-example) (list (posn 1 1) (posn 1 2) (posn 1 3)))
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that Racket structures are opaque by default, and equality on opaque structures won't look at the members. See [Structure Comparisons](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html#(part._struct-equal)) for more details, and on how to fix it.

For a quick-fix, you make your posn structure transparent:

```
(struct posn (x y) #:transparent)
```

The issue isn't restricted to `check-equal?`. `equal?` also shows this behaviour, if we use your example above:

```
(equal?
 (snake-segs snake-example)
 (list (posn 1 1) (posn 1 2) (posn 1 3))) ; false
```